# Valor de Palabras

Tags: javascript

Necesito crear una forma de al ingresar una palabra se sumen los valores de sus letras de acuerdo a su posición en el abecedario. Tengo este objeto con cada letra y su valor:

```
let abc = {
        a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5, f:6, g:7, h:8, i:9, j:10, k:11, l:12, m:13, n:14, o:15, p:16, q:17, r:18, s:19, t:20, u:21, v:22, w:23, x:24, y:25, z:26
    }
```

Lo que intenté hacer fue utilizar Object.keys y Object.values para retornar las propiedades y valores en distintos arrays y luego ir comparando, pero al mostrar la suma me devuelve NaN.

```
    const arrABCKeys = Object.keys(abc);
    const arrABCValues = Object.values(abc);
    let palabra1 = prompt("Ingresar palabra");
    let suma1;
    for (let i = 0; i < palabra1.length; i++) {
        if (palabra1[i] = arrABCKeys[i]) {
            suma1 = suma1 + arrABCValues[i];
        }
    }
    console.log(suma1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu `for` recorre cada letra de la palabra ingresada en el `prompt`, entonces, podemos buscar cada letra en las claves de tu objeto `abc` y así obtener los valores de ellos. No necesitas usar `Object.keys` y `Object.values`, `tan solo bastaría con esta condicional:

```
if (abc[letra]) {
  suma1 += abc[letra];
}
```

Aquí digo que si la letra existe en las claves del objeto, sumo el valor de esa letra a la variable `suma`, así vas acumulando el valor en la variable, teniendo la suma de todos los valores de las letras encontradas en tu objeto.

Código (explicación en comentarios):

```js
let abc = {
  a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5, f: 6, g: 7, h: 8, i: 9, j: 10, k: 11, l: 12, m: 13, n: 14, o: 15, p: 16, q: 17, r: 18, s: 19, t: 20, u: 21, v: 22, w: 23, x: 24, y: 25, z: 26
}

let palabra1 = prompt("Ingresar palabra");
let suma1 = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < palabra1.length; i++) {
  // Uso "toLowerCase()" para que cada palabra esté en minusculas y podamos usarlo como clave del objeto.
  let letra = palabra1[i].toLowerCase();
  // Si la letra existe en el objeto, sumo su valor a la variable suma
  if (abc[letra]) {
    suma1 += abc[letra]; // así ingreso al valor de la clave [letra], que sería cada letra de la palabra del promt.
  }
}

console.log(suma1);
```

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias

Comment: @FedericoPerezJofre no hay de que, saludos!

Answer (score 3):

Yo agregaría otro bucle que recorra las propiedades del objeto dentro del ciclo que recorre la palabra. Luego se comparo ambas.

```
const arrABCKeys = Object.keys(abc);
const arrABCValues = Object.values(abc);

let palabra1 = prompt("Ingresar palabra");
let suma1 = 0; // Inicializar con 0
for (let i = 0; i < palabra1.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arrABCKeys.length; j++) {
        if (palabra1[i] == arrABCKeys[j]) { // utiliza == para comparar
            suma1 = suma1 + arrABCValues[j];
        }
    }
}

console.log(suma1);
```

Comment: También sirve, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

En una línea de código:

```js
const suma = palabra =>Array.from(palabra).reduce( (a,i)=> a+= parseInt(i,36) -9,0);
    
console.log(suma("alo"));
console.log(suma("Yussef"));
console.log(suma("Prueba"));
```

Explicación:

- Transformamos el `string` en un `array` usando `Array.from`
- Usamos `reduce` para recorrer el array y sumar cada letra
- Usamos parseInt(i,36) para cambiar la letra por número

`parseInt(i,36)` convierte un número en base 36 a decimal (base 10).

Un número en base 36 tiene lo siguientes digitos: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,....z. Entonces la a=10, b=11 , c=12, etc. Por lo que restando `9` se obtiene el número decesado => a=1, b=2, c=3, etc